# Java runs in CMD but not in Powershell

Tags: java, powershell, jvm, classpath, java-8

So, I am not new to Java and compiling in cmd but I am pretty new to using windows powershell. I have 'javac' and 'java' commands running fine in CMD and all java programs compile using netbeans and eclipse. I can also use javac inside windows powershell with no problems, but when attempting to run a java program, i.e. java MyProgram, after compiling it I get the following error...

```
 Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\jvm.cfg
```

Now I am running Java 8, so I have no idea why it would be looking for a file like this since CMD confirms that both 'java' and 'javac' are running version 8 and have the correct path set, or they would not run there. And please do not just tell me more about setting the paths because I have checked and checked and checked again. Also, I have made sure that anything that is related to java version 7 that I could find has been uninstalled / deleted.

Well, any advice would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Try to print JAVA_HOME in you powershell

Comment: Might you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: you can check it by `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` won't work. To print `JAVA_HOME` from PowerShell, just enter `$env:JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: By the way, we really need an example of command you're trying to run. I think it's a problem of your environment, not PowerShell or your Java program. You know, classpath issues are hard to debug sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start you application using a small cmd oder bat-File. Powershell does a lot of parsing and destroys your call. I usualy use something like this:

```
$Result = Invoke-Expression "cmd /c $Tempbat"
```

One alternative is to use the stop-parsing character: --%

```
icacls c:\scripts --% /grant ***\ScriptAdmin:(CI)(OI)F
```